# Using jQuery Mobile navigation model pages (data-role='page') can I modularize the code by splitting the pages across different files?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Below is jQuery page structure which is layed out on one page. jQuery mobile treats each data-role='page' like a different page that users can navigate around.

My project is now getting pretty big and I have 10 data-role='page' pages on the same .php file and I'd like to split them over 10 pages but still keep the functionality jQuery Mobile provides. How can I do this?

```
<body> 
<!-- Start of first page -->
<div data-role="page" id="foo">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>I'm first in the source order so I'm shown as the page.</p>      
    <p>View internal page called <a href="#bar">bar</a></p> 
</div>

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div>
</div><!-- /page -->

<!-- Start of second page -->
<div data-role="page" id="bar">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Bar</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">       
</div>

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div>
</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery mobile have two page templates.

One have every page placed inside a single HTML file, like in your case. It is also called multipage template.

Second one have 1 page per 1 HTML file. And it is called multi-HTML template.

Read more about them [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/multipage-template-vs-multi-html-template-in-jquery-mobile/).

What you need is a multi-HTML template. Here a working example:

#### HTML 1 - index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index",function () {
            $(document).on('click', "#changePage",function () {     
                $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
            }); 
        }); 

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#second",function () {
            var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
            parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
            alert(parameter);
        });         
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <a data-role="button" id="changePage">Javascript change page example</a>
                      <a href="second.html" data-transition="slide">Direct link button</a>
        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

#### HTML 2 - second.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">

        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

There's one more thing you need to know. Only first HTML file can have more then one inner **`data-role="page"`**. Every other HTML page can have ONLY 1 **`data-role="page"`** inside. Reason for this is described **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**. If you need more information just give me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the single page template

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/page-template.html

That or you could just split the page you currently have into several php files and include them all into your main php file outputting the markup as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, here is an example:

```
<li><a href="masterclass.php" data-transition="slide">Master Class</a></li>
```